# Gunicorn, nginx, django, inside of a docker container. Gunicorn successfully runs on port 80 but nginx fails

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I'm trying to set up a simple blogging site that I wrote using the django framework. The website works except that it isn't serving static files. I imagine that's because nginx isn't running. However, when I configure it to run on any port other than 80 I get the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 172.17.0.1:9000 failed (99: Cannot assign requested address)
```

When I run it on a port that is already being used by gunicorn I get the following error:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

My nginx configuration file is as follows:

```
upstream django {
        server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}

server {
    listen 172.17.0.1:9000;
    server_name my.broken.blog;
    index index.html;
    location = /assets/favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /assets {
        autoindex on;
        alias /var/www/html/mysite/assets;
        }
    location / {
        autoindex on;
        uwsgi_pass unix:///run/uwsgi/django/socket;
        include /var/www/html/mysite/mysite/uwsgi_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        }
}
```

But if I run nginx without starting guincorn it runs properly but I get a 403 forbidden error.

Going with the suggested answer I don't get any errors, but the site is returning 403 forbidden and doesn't present the part of the website gunicorn is supposed to deliver.

Comment: server { 
     listen  80;
    server_name   172.17.0.1;

Comment: specify port in listen

Comment: use the following to setup static files

Comment: location /static/  {
        root /path/to/static
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure Nginx and Gunicorn in following way to make it work,

1. Use unix socket to comminicate between nginx and gunicron rather than running gunicorn in some port

Create a unit file for gunicorn in the following location

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service

[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=nginx
WorkingDirectory=/path-to-project-folder
ExecStart=/<path-to-env>/bin/gunicorn --workers 9 --bind unix:/path-to-sockfile/<blog>.sock app.wsgi:application 

Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then start and enable  gunicorn service
It will generate a sock file in the specified path.

```
sudo systemctl enable gunicorn
sudo systemctl start gunicorn
```

Note: Choose the suitable number of workers for gunicorn, can sepecify log files as follows

ExecStart=//bin/gunicorn --workers 9 --bind unix:/path-to-sockfile/.sock app.wsgi:application --access-logfile /var/log/gunicorn/access.log --error-logfile /var/log/error.log

2. create a new configuration file specific to the project in /etct/nginx rather than edit the default nginx.conf

> nano /etc/nginx/blog.conf

and add the following lines ( can also add the file in /etc/nginx/default.d/)

```
server {
            listen 80;
            server_name 172.17.0.1;  # your Ip
        
            location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
            location /static/ {
                root /path-to-static-folder;
            }
            location /media/  {
                root /path-to-media-folder;
            }
    
        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/path-to-sock-file/<blog-sock-file>.sock;
        }
    }
```

include the /etc/nginx/blog.conf to nignx.conf

```
---------
----------
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/blog.conf;   # the new conf file added
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
    ------
-------
```

run sudo nginx -t   // to check for errors in nginx configuration.
run  sudo systemctl nginx restart

refer: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: I edited my post to include your suggestion/error. Thanks for your reply!