# Ngnix Gunicorn Django bare minimum site-available

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

My gunicorn server is running at:

```
123.123.123.123:8000 //my server ip and
sth.sthmore.org:8000 // my domain name
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/mypro     // mypro is a filename

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name sth.sthmore.org;
    location / {
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;  // 123.123.123.123:8000 doesn't work either
       proxy_set_header Host $host;  // no idea what is this for
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  // no idea ...
    }
}
```

This comes from here : https://gunicorn.org/#deployment

If i call 123.123.123.123 or sth.sthmore.org I get the default ngnix page and not the gunicorn page which runs on ...:8000.

**How does the right file should look like?**

Comment: you need to include /etc/nginx/sites-available/mypro  to the default  nginx.conf file( /etc/nginx/nginx.conf)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70588498/gunicorn-nginx-django-inside-of-a-docker-container-gunicorn-successfully-run/70590349#70590349

Comment: Thanks that helped, but I still got "502 Bad Gateway" could there be a gunicorn problem? Or is it save to assume if gunicorn runs at x.x.x.x:8000 and works that it's a ngnix problem? I get '/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service:1: Invalid section header '[Unit]Description=gunicorn daemon'' in logs.

Comment: it might be gunicorn issue. You don't need to run gunicorn in port 8000,  if running as a service.  either one is needed

Comment: if running as service  use  proxy_pass http://unix:/path-to-sock-file/<blog-sock-file>.sock;

Comment: then remove proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;