# Ngnix + Django + Gunicorn not found static and media

Tags: django, nginx

I'm trying to deploy the site on the server, but static and media are not loaded on it. I tried to juggle the url pattern and config nginx, but all in vain. The most interesting thing is that he loads only index.css, and does not see all the others

```
server {
    listen 443;
    server_name domain.com;

    location /media {
        alias /root/djangoproj/media;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /root/djangoproj/static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_no_cache 1;
        proxy_cache_bypass 1;
    }
}
```

I tried to juggle the url pattern and config nginx

Comment: I have been searching for information on the internet for an hour and a half (approximately), but nothing helps

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70588498/gunicorn-nginx-django-inside-of-a-docker-container-gunicorn-successfully-run/70590349#70590349

Comment: location /static/ ,     put last  slash   '/'

Comment: put slash and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70588498/gunicorn-nginx-django-inside-of-a-docker-container-gunicorn-successfully-run/70590349#70590349 not workin for me

Comment: Have you run `collectstatic`?